# Identifying and Downloading Dependency for an Offline PC

Tags: dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

My pc have no internet connection. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition. I always  download the package from another pc having net connection into my pendrive and when I try to install a package it always shows that dependency is required. How can I solve this problem?

Is there any command in ubuntu so that I can see all the dependency along with corresponding url to download of a particular package?