# How to install Wine from already downloaded package?

Tags: installation, wine, kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)
>   [Identifying and Downloading Dependency for an Offline PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14478/identifying-and-downloading-dependency-for-an-offline-pc)

I downloaded Wine from Windows but don't know how to install it in Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: What file exactly have you downloaded?. Where did you download it from?. What are you trying to achieve?.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How do I install wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have downloaded the .deb package, then installing it comes down to the following command: `sudo dpkg -i your-package.deb`. You might run into dependency problems, though. You'll have to find all the missing dependencies, download the packages and install them in the same way. Of course, those packages themselves might lead to missing depencies, and therefore, ...

Alternatively, just use apt: `sudo apt-get install wine`. It will solve the dependency problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to install Wine, then `sudo apt-get install wine` on a Terminal will do the job.  Your wine home directory is held at **~/.wine**.