# Installing apt module without internet

Tags: apt, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identifying and Downloading Dependency for an Offline PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14478/identifying-and-downloading-dependency-for-an-offline-pc)

How can I take an apt module from an internet enabled Ubuntu and get it to a USB for a non internet install?

I am wanting the following which are available through apt. I am sure there will be more that I end up needing.

- [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)
- libcurl3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to...

1. Goto [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) or [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu);
2. Find the package you need ([gimp packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/gimp) or [gimp launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp));
3. Check if there are any dependencies that you do not have installed ([gimp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/gimp)) ;
4. Download the .DEB's you need from the launchpad page <-- this can be annoying as hell;
5. Copy/paste these downloads to USB;
6. Install them on the other server. <sub>You need to install these in the correct order: lowest dependency 1st <-- this can be annoying as hell too.</sub>

<sub>edit: I would suggest picking up the machine and carry it to an internet connection if you want wine</sub>

Comment: Why launchpad and not the more obvious http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: I'll edit it in :) (I had launchpad open at the time of typing :D)

Comment: I am not allowed to connect this to internet. I have to install everything I need through controlled file transfer. I found WINE in the Launchpad which I started using before your last edit. I now have Chrome and its dependencies (for browser-based non-internet apps). Also have WINE, getting its dependencies now.

Comment: i think if you use `dpkg -i` with all the packages in one line it will install them in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

APT saves downloaded packages to the filesystem here:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/
```

You may be able to save some time/bandwidth over downloading.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options including a gui see the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline). The easiest option would probably be the [Synaptic Download Script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic/PackageDownloadScript). Most of these options including Synaptic Download Script allow different operating systems to be used (Windows OSX and Linux).